# How to make reload page function after submit data in php

Tags: php, mysql, web

I want to reload page after submitting data, but I got some problem with that, i've tried several ways but it doesn't work. here's my code :

here's the ajax :

```
$('#form-tambah-posisi').submit(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Posisi/prosesTambah'); ?>',
        data: data
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        var out = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        tampilPosisi();
        if (out.status == 'form') {
            $('.form-msg').html(out.msg);
            effect_msg_form();
            location.reload();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("form-tambah-posisi").reset();
            $('#tambah-posisi').modal('hide');
            $('.msg').html(out.msg);
            effect_msg();
        }
    })

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

here's the controller :

```
 public function prosesTambah() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tgl_date', 'Date', 'trim|required');

    $data   = $this->input->post();


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $result = $this->M_posisi->insert($data);

        if ($result > 0) {
            $out['status'] = '';
            $out['msg'] = show_succ_msg('Add Success!', '20px');


        } else {
            $out['status'] = '';
            $out['msg'] = show_err_msg('Add Failed!', '20px');
        }
    } else {
        $out['status'] = 'form';
        $out['msg'] = show_err_msg(validation_errors());
    }

    echo json_encode($out);
}
```

Looking forward for solution. thank's.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "reload page function"? Try not to use a name, try to explain what it actually is you want to achieve. That code you posted certainly will not reload anything, why should it?

Comment: i've edited my code with addition "location.reload()". i've tried this way but it still didn't work. can you tell me where i should put my code in order to reload

Comment: How are you calling that function, we need more context. If you call it via JS/AJAX you can reload the page after you get the response there, if you don't use AJAX the page will be reloaded by the browser usually.

Comment: `location.reload();` isn't PHP, it's JavaScript. Apparently you're outputting JSON so I guess you call this function via Ajax, correct? If so, you should do the refresh in JavaScript after the Ajax request is finished.

Comment: that's why I ask how to make it reload automatically after the button@xander

Comment: sorry, i've changed my code

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can simply use this :

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
```

where you want page reload

Answer (score 0):

You can send headers to a customer.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 location.reload(true);
```

you can force to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true. check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)